# error in exponential of an equation

Tags: math-mode

Please  help with the exponential part of eqn. Getting error. I am using overleaf

```
\begin{equation}
   p(r)= (r/\upsilon^2)e^((r^2)/2\upsilon^2) ;  
   (0>=r>=\infty);
   p(r)= 0 ; (r<=0).
\end{equation}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you add an MWE that produces the error you are getting?

Comment: exponential is not displayed properly. also i want new line for each of those conditions....

Comment: If I use your code snippet in an article document class, I don't get any errors. Without an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) it's not possible to say why you are getting any errors.  And for multiple equations, you should use other environments like `align` etc. For your case, you may also consider the `cases` environment.

Comment: You need braces `{....}` for `e^{....} ` to work. This should be listed in any decent latex introduction

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
OP's code after correcting the exponential and inequality symbols. 
\begin{equation}
   p(r)= (r/\upsilon^2)e^{((r^2)/2\upsilon^2)} ;  
   (0 \geq r \geq \infty);
   p(r)= 0 ; (r \leq 0).
\end{equation}

Multiple equations using \verb|IEEEeqnarray| environment.
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCll}
   p(r) &=& (r/\upsilon^2)e^{((r^2)/2\upsilon^2)};  
   & \quad 0 \geq r \geq \infty; \\
   p(r) &=& 0; & \quad r \leq 0.
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

Using \verb|cases| environment.
\begin{equation}
    p(r) = 
    \begin{cases}
    (r/\upsilon^2)e^{((r^2)/2\upsilon^2)}; & 0 \geq r \geq \infty;; \\
    p(r)= 0; & r \leq 0.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]